# Is CSS3 box-flex working as intended in this example?

Tags: html, css

I was writing the layout of an app using the box-flex property (in Chrome) and I have found a strange behaviour, in my opinion, that I am wondering if might be a bug or that I just ignore the reason for those workings.

The code looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5tuCh/

There is a weird "div" resize when resizing the "textarea" so that the dimension of the "div" minus the "textarea" is equal to the dimension of the second "div", in order to satisfy "box-flex:1.0" I guess. Now if the reason for box-flex was making it easier to arrange the layout, this behaviour makes it unusable in this case.

Might it be that I am missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact correct behaviour. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-box-flex):

> The containing box allocates the available extra space in proportion
>   to the flex value of each of the content elements.

In your example, div.text boxes actually render with a height, meaning that any space beyond that would be spread evenly (or, rather, according to the flex ratio) between the elements. Setting `height:0` on these elements would force behavior that I believe you're after (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5tuCh/16/); I also had to remove the `height:100%` declaration on your textarea to prevent it from collapsing inside an element with zero height. I'd speculate that you may accomplish the textarea to take up full height of the parent element by setting its box-flex property as well.

### Update:

OP's having issues with textarea behaviour could possibly be addressed by the following style:

```
textarea { 
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;right:10px;bottom:10px;left:10px;
    resize:none;
}​
```

The parent element, of course, has to have `position:relative` set, which would result in the textarea taking up all available space in the container (w/10px spacing between the borders). Not sure if that's what you were after though. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5tuCh/36/

Comment: I've tried it, and the textarea won't fill the parent with box-flex. I've tried using height:100% and width:100% for the textarea, and while the width works well, the height goes beyond boundaries, even using box-sizing:border-box. This is totally counter-intuitive. Why is it like this??

Comment: @el_techinic0: could be the issue with rendering replaced elements; worth a separate question imo if the update above doesn't work for you. Could try playing with *contenteditable* instead

Comment: Since it was causing more trouble than helping, I went with the contenteditable option and used usual html-css layout techniques. Thanks for the tip!